# How to create a control/checking script in powershell?

Tags: powershell, controls, verification

I am new to powershell scripting. I've created a script in powershell, and I would like to create a script to verify that it has been executed properly

For example to verify that the purge has been executed.

Could you help me?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why would you not just have the script write a log of the actions it performs, then review the log? No log or partial log = script didn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this is somewhat broad as there are hundreds of ways to do this, but what I would probably go with is writing an entry somewhere at the end of the first script (Event Log, text file, SQL database) and letting the second script just test for the presence of the output, assuming having a script check another script is a hard requirement.

Look into 
    `Get-Help Write-EventLog`
    `Get-Help Get-EventLog`
    `Get-Help Out-File`
    `Get-Help Get-Content`

SQL might be a little too much for a new sheller, but if you're interested, google around for `System.Data.SqlClient`

If a second script isn't required, you may be better suited using a try/catch block within your first script, using the catch to notify you (via something like `Send-MailMessage`) or log the failure someone for later perusal.